# How can I prove this statement about two vectors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

How can I go about proving that $A=(A\cdot \hat n)\hat n+(\hat n\times A)\times \hat n$ where "$\cdot$" and "$\times$" indicate the dot and cross products respectively, $A$ is an arbitrary vector, and $\hat n$ is a unit vector in some fixed direction?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [vector triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) and the fact that $\hat n \cdot \hat n = 1$:

$$A=(A\cdot \hat n)\hat n+(\hat n\times A)\times \hat n$$

$$=(A\cdot \hat n)\hat n+ \left(-(A \cdot \hat n)\hat n + (\hat n\cdot \hat n)A\right)$$

$$=(A\cdot \hat n)\hat n- (A \cdot \hat n)\hat n + A$$

$$= A$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I've literally spent the last three hours mucking around with the vector components and I never would have thought that the solution was this simple. Gosh darn it lol